# gazebo binary version for ROS with self collision bug fixed

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Does anybody knows when if there will be a binary version of Gazebo with the self collision bug fixed for ROS users?

Or some tips how to install gazebo from source under ROS.

Thanks,
Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/279/gazebo-binary-version-for-ros-with-self-collision-bug-fixed/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2012-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The solution to your problem is to remove all versions of Gazebo and ROS, and start with a fresh install using the binary versions of Gazebo and ROS only.

It seems that your system has many different versions installed which are cause conflicts.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[Here are instructions](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/Install) for installing the binary or source version of gazebo for use with ROS.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-11-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2012-11-29**:
Hi, I got the chance to test the instructions, sadly they did not work. I have ubuntu 12.04 with ROS fuerte installed on my PC. When installing the Pre-compiled binaries it does not come with the new gazebo.

**Comment by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on 2012-11-29**:
@nkoenig, I think AndreiHaidu will be unable to mark his own answer as correct because of low karma. Can you do that for him? I'm thinking if a few people get enough karma to vote, the questions will be filtered better, and we'll get better participation.